# created lwc component with csv file to process to salesforce apex class

Tags: salesforce-lightning

Created lwc component to import csv file , and it shouls process to apex class and then batch class. but  in soql query we are retreiving null values where we used filter criteria with value coming from csv in salesforce

SOql query should fetch the values